# How can weighted K-NN decrease accuracy?

Tags: k-nearest-neighbour

I have heard that weighted K-NN improves the accuracy.But in my case, the accuracy decreases.Can anyone suggest why there is a decrease in accuracy?

Comment: This can have million reasons...can you provide more details e.g. which distance function you use, which features are involved, value of "k", which kind of data (textual, images, etc.). In general you can not say that a weighted kNN outperforms a regular kNN...It strongly depends on the mentioned factors

Comment: I have used euclidean distance and my K value is five and I have to classify signals.Some of the features used are :max peak,area,mean ...

Comment: Try the most basic thing. Use a 1-NN, Manhatten distance, and apply a 10 fold cross validation regarding both, the weighted and the regular NN. By the way which kind of weights are you applying on the features? Are they all sum up to 1 ? How do you apply them? Do you use a feature ranking technique? If so, which one?

Comment: @Unhandledexception -I used 1-NN also.But there was no difference between weighted and regular NN.I used inverse squared weighting.However,can you give examples  where weighted accuracy decreases.

Comment: I also tried using exponential decaying function exp(-x) as the weighting function ,x is the distance.This time the accuracy remains same.I feel I am missing something on weighted k-nn .can u pls explain this behaviour of k-nn?

Comment: I believe that the weights are applied to the wrong (irrelevant) features. Have you tried feature delection or extraction techniques (e.g., pca, factor analysis, ...)? Try to apply weighting to those features that were found by the methods to be most promising...